# InaccessibleTensorError occurs when using model.fit of custom model in tf2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Here's my code**

```py
#Here's my custom GRU layer
class GRU(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(GRU, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.h_init = False

    def build(self, input_shape):
        dims = input_shape[-1]
        self.steps = input_shape[-2]

        self.wr = self.add_weight(name="wr", shape=[dims+self.units, self.units], initializer="glorot_normal")
        self.br = self.add_weight(name="br", shape=[self.units], initializer="zeros")

        self.wz = self.add_weight(name="wz", shape=[dims+self.units, self.units], initializer="glorot_normal")
        self.bz = self.add_weight(name="bz", shape=[self.units], initializer="zeros")

        self.wn = self.add_weight(name="wn", shape=[dims+self.units, self.units], initializer="glorot_normal")
        self.bn = self.add_weight(name="bn", shape=[self.units], initializer="zeros")

        super(GRU, self).build(input_shape)

    def dense_forward(self, w, b, x, activation):
        return activation(x @ w + b)

    def update_step(self, x):
        self.z.assign(self.dense_forward(self.wz, self.bz, tf.concat([x, self.h], axis=1), tf.nn.sigmoid))
        self.r.assign(self.dense_forward(self.wr, self.br, tf.concat([x, self.h], axis=1), tf.nn.sigmoid))
        self.n.assign(self.dense_forward(self.wn, self.bn, tf.concat([x, self.r * self.h], axis=1), tf.nn.tanh))

        # z = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.wz @ tf.concat([x, self.h], axis=1) + self.bz)
        # r = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.wr @ tf.concat([x, self.h], axis=1) + self.br)
        # n = tf.nn.tanh(self.wn @ tf.concat([x, r * self.h], axis=1)+ self.bn)

        self.h = (1 - self.z) * self.h + self.z * self.n

    def call(self, x):
        if not self.h_init:
            initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
            self.h = initializer(shape=(x.shape[0], self.units))
            self.z = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[x.shape[0], self.units], dtype=tf.float32))
            self.r = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[x.shape[0], self.units], dtype=tf.float32))
            self.n = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[x.shape[0], self.units], dtype=tf.float32))
            self.h_init = True

        assert x.shape[1] == self.steps

        for step in tf.range(self.steps):
            self.update_step(x[:, step, :])

        return self.h
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return tf.TensorShape([None, self.units])

    def get_config(self):  
        config = super(GRU, self).get_config()
        config.update({'units': self.units})
        return config

#Here's my custom dense layer
class Dense(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, activation=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            name="kernel", shape=[batch_input_shape[-1], self.units],
            initializer="glorot_normal")
        self.bias = self.add_weight(
            name="bias", shape=[self.units], initializer="zeros")
        super().build(batch_input_shape)

    def call(self, X):
        return self.activation(X @ self.kernel + self.bias)

    def compute_output_shape(self, batch_input_shape):
        return tf.TensorShape(batch_input_shape.as_list()[:-1] + [self.units])

    def get_config(self):         
        base_config = super().get_config()         
        return {**base_config, "units": self.units,                 
                "activation": keras.activations.serialize(self.activation)}

'''
gru = GRU(units=32)
gru.build(input_shape=(None, 128, 2))
gru.compute_output_shape(input_shape=(None, 128, 2))

dense = Dense(1)
dense.build((None, 32, 1))
dense.compute_output_shape(batch_input_shape=tf.TensorShape([None, 32, 1]))
'''


#Here's the model to use my custom GRU for regression
class GRUReg(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(GRUReg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gru = GRU(units=units)
        self.dense = Dense(1)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.gru.build(input_shape)
        self.dense.build(self.gru.compute_output_shape(input_shape))

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.gru(x)
        return self.dense(x)
```

**Here's the training codes**

```py
model = GRUReg(32)
model.build([None, 128, 2])
model(tf.ones((2, 128, 2)))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])

reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
```

**Then fit**

```py
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

**An error occurs in the model.fit line**
Here's the **Error**

```sh
:13 call  *
        x = self.gru(x)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:776 __call__
        outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py:639 mark_as_return
        return nest.map_structure(_mark_as_return, outputs)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py:568 map_structure
        structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py:568 
        structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py:625 _mark_as_return
        return_tensor = acd.mark_as_return(tensor)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\auto_control_deps.py:167 mark_as_return
        tensor = array_ops.identity(tensor)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py:180 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py:267 identity
        ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py:3829 identity
        "Identity", input=input, name=name)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py:742 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py:591 _create_op_internal
        inp = self.capture(inp)
    D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py:641 capture
        % (tensor, tensor.graph, self))

    InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("add_4:0", shape=(2, 32), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=gru_reg_6_gru_11_while_body_19141, id=2570529255624); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=keras_graph, id=2566523294088).
```

I wrote the code out of the similar codes from a tf2 book which made me more baffled.
Them I googled the error but cannot find an appropriate solution to the Error...

My OS:win10

Tensorflow's Version:'2.1.0'

Python: '3.7'

CudaToolKit：10.1

Graphics Card：GTX1660Ti